# SAX parser recursive parsing

Tags: sax

I have an XML file which has same tags in another.

I need to write a java function using SAX Parser API. This function will be recursive.

Does anybody has some example.

My Sample XML is like this

```
            </Split>

            <Remainder>
                <Split type="unique|range|equal" value1="" value2="">
                    <Split type="unique|range|equal" value1="" value2="">
                    </Split>
                </Split>
                <Remainder/>
            </Remainder>
        </FilterSplit>
        <Split attr_name="surname" type="unique">
            <Split attr_name="kidName" type="unique">
            </Split>
        </Split>
    <Split>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do recursive parsing with a push parser like SAX directly. Parse the document to the DOM (I think there is SAXDomBuilder or similar), then recursively process the DOM. Or use a streaming XML parser such as StAX, XPP or kXML